# Webmail and domain. I need a solution to this problem

Tags: dns, webmail

Im hoping you geniuses here at stackoverflow can help me with this.

Recently i had to point my domain name to a network on [Ning.com](http://ning.com) to [map and merge the site with the domain](http://help.ning.com/cgi-bin/ning.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=2920), so i had to add an A and CNAME record. This disconnected the link between my domain and my web host and because of this my friends cant access their email anymore. [Ning](http://ning.com) doesnt offer webmail either. And im not sure if i want to use Google Apps.

**Is there a way i can retain the new domain pointer to the network on [Ning.com](http://ning.com) and a pointer to my web host for the webmail?** Or is there any other options i can take?

Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it an option for you to create a new A record to a subdomain like webmail.mydomain.com?

Not sure if this qualifies as a comment or answer, depends on your situation.

This is really more of a serverfault question also, if you want to try there.

Answer (score 1):

Try Google Apps.  You said you weren't sure if you wanted to use GA, but there's no better way to find out than to try it.  It's easy to set up and if you don't like it, you can always disable it.  I have personally had a good experience using GA for webmail on a custom domain.